# Qt-how to connect a function to a signal in qml with python? using QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: python, qt, qml

this is the qml file.   "main.qml"

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow{
    visible:true
    width:640
    height:480
    id:window
    title:asTr("editor")

    signal show(string text)



    TextArea{
        text:"hello"
        onTextChanged:show(text);
    }

}
```

this is the python code .   "main.py"

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

def show(text):
    print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.load('main.qml')
  win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to connect the signal "show" in main.qml to the slot "show" in main.py. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important: don't call your signal `show`, [show](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#show) already is a slot of the QWindow. If you change the name to something else, then you can simply connect the signal defined in qml in your python code:

qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow{
    visible:true
    width:640
    height:480
    id:window
    title: "editor"

    signal textUpdated(string text)


    TextArea{
        text:"hello"
        onTextChanged: textUpdated(text);
    }

}
```

python:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

def show(text):
    print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.load('main.qml')
  win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
  win.textUpdated.connect(show)
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: hello ! could i ask you another question?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554068/qt-how-to-change-the-content-in-webview-with-qml)